# How do I filter by a parameterized type irrespective of its parameter types?

Tags: c#, templates, reflection

I want to know if a type is IQueryable.

```
var t = typeof(IQueryable<int>);
bool isQueryable = (t is IQueryable); // false
bool isAssignableFrom = t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IQueryable)); // false
bool nameStartsWithIQueryable = t.Name.StartsWith("IQueryable"); // true
```

The third way - looking at the beginning of the type name - works but feels like a hack.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GetGenericTypeDefinition`:

```
bool isQueryable = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>);
```

If you need to handle deeper ancestries (where you are checking aganist the base type), you can write a helper method:

```
public static bool IsType(Type type, Type ancestor)
{
    while (type != null)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType)
            type = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        if (type == ancestor)
            return true;
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Calling it like so:

```
bool isQueryable = IsType(typeof(IQueryable<int>), typeof(IQueryable<>));
```

(Note that this won't help with base types that implement other interfaces, since checking against that would require a lot more code using `Type.GetInterfaces` recursively.)

Answer (score 1):

You just have the `IsAssignableFrom` backwards, it should be:

```
typeof(IQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(t);
```

I prefer using IsAssignableFrom in the general case because when you're not dealing with interfaces, IsAssignableFrom will tell you true if a class as an implict user-defined conversion operator. Plus, you don't have to deal with type hierarchies, etc...

Comment: This only works because `IQueryable<T>` *happens* to have a non-generic `IQueryable` that is also a base interface.  It does not work in the general case.